# for loop using uint64 won't stop

Tags: for-loop, go

Is there an explanation why for loop using uint64 wouldn't stop at 0?

I've tried the same for loop with int and it works as expected.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
  i := uint64(5)
  for ; i>=uint64(0); i-- {
  fmt.Printf("step %d\n", i)
  }
}
```

I would expect this function to stop at output `step 0` but it overflows the int and continues forever with `step 18446744073709551615` and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop continues while `i >= 0`, but an unsigned integer is **always** greater than or equal to zero. Unsigned integers cannot be negative so your loop never terminates.

Try changing `i` to `int64` and see if it behaves differently. :-)

Best of luck.